# Get value from seletected dropdown with same class class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 tabs which shows geographic details of 5 states. on each tab there is a drop down which lists main cities of those states. by default the all cities are set to "Total population" which shows the live population below the drop down. i have a function which is called every 3 seconds. So when the user changes the city the current population for that city will be shown below.

on each tab the dropdown has the class `.city`

below is the jquery function which is called every 3 seconds

```
function doCity() {
    var feed =   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php')?>/feed/population',
        data: $('.city').val(),
              // dataType: 'json',
        success: function (feed) {
            $('.current_value_alaska').html(feed); 
            $('.current_value_block2').html(feed); 
            $('.current_value_block3').html(feed); 
            $('.current_value_block4').html(feed);  
        },
        complete: function (feed) {                       
            setTimeout(doCity, interval);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<select name="city" class="city">
    <option value="5">City1</option>
    <option value="12">City2</option>
    <option value="13">City3</option>
    <option value="14">City4</option>
    <option value="15">City5</option>
</select>

<select name="city" class="city">
    <option value="31">City 31</option>
    <option value="32">City 32</option>
    <option value="33">City 33</option>
    <option value="44">City 34</option>
    <option value="35">City 35</option>
</select>
```

the problem is, on the first tab when i change the city the correct population is shown and it updates every 3 seconds... but on the other tabs when i change the city it doesn't show the population of the city selected..

can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: not complete set of code , how you are calling doCity ?

Comment: Are you having separate forms for all the tabs??

Comment: There is no sense to do `setTimeout` first place, use `$('.city').on('change')` event. Second, give us more code (create a Fiddle?). 3rd and maybe most important, what do you expect in return for `$('.city').val()`, when `$('.city')` is an array of jQuery objects?

Comment: as you you have multiple selects with class `city`, the data in your ajax call from `$('.city').val()` will have the value of first instance only. 
you should be passing the value of each `select` element separately to **doCity** function

Answer (score 0):

Since you `doCity()` on dropdown change, you need to organize your code other way. Add `onchange` event to your dropdowns and only than do your AJAX calls.

You can see it working on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34g5wh4z/1/), same code is below:

```js
var allTabSelectors = $('.tab_select a');
var allTabs = $('.tab');
var spinner = $('.spinner');
$('.tab_select a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  var thisLink = $(this);
  var thisHref = thisLink.attr('href');
  allTabs.hide();
  $(thisHref).show();
  allTabSelectors.removeClass('active');
  thisLink.addClass('active');
});
$('.tab_select a:eq(0)').trigger('click');
$('.city').on('change', function(e) {
  var thisSelect = $(this);
  var thisValue = thisSelect.val();
  var thisTab = thisSelect.closest('.tab');
  var thisResult = thisTab.find('.result');
  spinner.show();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        city: thisValue,
        html: "<p>We posted: " + thisValue + "</p>"
    },
    success: function(feed) {
      thisResult.html(feed);
      spinner.hide();
    },
    error: function(e) {
     spinner.hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h3,
p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.tab_select li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.tab_select li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: none #ccc;
}

.tab_select li a.active {
  background: none #fff;
}

.tabs {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: none rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) center center;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab_select">
  <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">
    <h3>
      Tab 1 content
    </h3>
    <p>
      <select name="city" class="city">
        <option value="">Select city</option>
        <option value="5">City1</option>
        <option value="12">City2</option>
        <option value="13">City3</option>
        <option value="14">City4</option>
        <option value="15">City5</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p class="result">
      -result comes here
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <h3>
      Tab 2 content
    </h3>
    <p>
      <select name="city" class="city">
        <option value="">Select city</option>
        <option value="5">City1</option>
        <option value="12">City2</option>
        <option value="13">City3</option>
        <option value="14">City4</option>
        <option value="15">City5</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p class="result">
      -result comes here
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="spinner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply take all selected options with :selected pseudo, and filter them by value. This is cool and clean one liner

```
$('.myclass option:selected').filter("[value=audi]")
```

Afterwards, you can grab this in a variable, and check if length > 0. (so you have a selected audi option).